# Create array with reversed words from user string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am creating a program in which a user enters a string of words (Ex: I love you), and the program returns an array of the words in the string spelled backwards (Ex: I evol ouy). However, I cannot get my code to properly compile, and tried debugging, but cannot see where the problem is.

I tried to look for similar problems here on Slack, but the problems are found were concerned with rearranging words from a string, (ex: you I love), and I cannot find a problem similar to mine, involving turning string into an Array and then manipulating the array.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string to see it in reverse: ");
    String userEntry = sc.nextLine();
    char[] entryToChar = userEntry.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(entryToChar));
    String[] splitInput = userEntry.split(" "); 
    String reverseWord = "";
    int temp;
    String[] reverseString = new String[splitInput.length]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < splitInput.length; i++) 
    {
        String word = splitInput[i];            


        for (int j = word.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) 
        {
            reverseWord = reverseWord + word.charAt(j);
        }            

        for (int k = 0; k < splitInput.length; k++) {
                temp = splitInput[i];
                splitInput[i] = reverseWord[j];
                reverseWord[j] = temp;

                }

     }  System.out.println("Your sttring with words spelled backwards is " + reverseWord[j]);
```

I am avoiding using the 'StringBuilder' method as I have not yet studied it, and trying to see if I can get the new string using swapping, as in the code below:

```
temp = splitInput[i];
splitInput[i] = reverseWord[j];
reverseWord[j] = temp;
```

Comment: If it doesn't compile, you should check the errors, the compiler shows you. At least post the errors here.

Comment: @Ridcully, this is where I get the compilation errors, but cannot find a way to fix them. I tried to do 'reverseString = reverseString + reverseWord[k], but it didn't work either.

Comment: There must be a lot of compilation errors. You've used wrong indexes in the loop as well.

Comment: What compiler errors exactly? Just copy them and paste them into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word, reverseWord;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string to see it in reverse: ");
        String userEntry = sc.nextLine();
```

userEntry: I love you

```
        String[] splitInput = userEntry.split(" ");
```

splitInput: [I, love, you]

```
        for (int i = 0; i < splitInput.length; i++)
        {
            word = splitInput[i];
            reverseWord = "";
            for (int j = word.length()-1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                reverseWord = reverseWord + word.charAt(j);
            }
            splitInput[i] = reverseWord;
        }
```

splitInput: [I, evol, uoy]

```
        System.out.println("Your string with words spelled backwards is: " + String.join(" ", splitInput));
    }
}
```

Your string with words spelled backwards is: I evol uoy

Comment: thank you! That took care of the problem, and I leaned how to make code logic clearer. I feel almost dumb for forgetting about the String.join method, but I am a beginner learner afterall...

Comment: My pleasure @AnneBailly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not getting compiled because `tmp` variable is declared as int while `splitInput[i]` is String.

The other problem is variable j is outside its block scope from where you are trying to access.

Make your logic clear before writing code to achieve correct result.

Answer (score 1):

A good Java programmer should know which tools exist in the language and make use of them in her/his design appropriately. I would suggest to use the class `StringBuilder`, which has a method for reversing the string. Your program could look like this:

```
while in.hasNext() {
  StringBuilder sb = in.next();
  sb.reverse();
  System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

If you want to write the reverse function yourself for practice then you can simply define a method that takes a string and returns a reversed string and call that method in place of `sb.reverse()`.

Please know that `String` in Java is an immutable object. You cannot modify it directly. You can have modified copies returned.
`StringBuilder` on the other hand allows the programmer to modify the object directly as you can see in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split original string into an array and then reverse each one and insert into the new array, here you can use `StringBuilder` as good practice.

```
class Testarray{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str = "I am Engineer";
        String[] spArray = str.split(" ");
        String farr[] = new String[spArray.length];

        for(int i=0;i<spArray.length;i++){
            String split = spArray[i];
            farr[i]=reverseString(split);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<farr.length;i++){
            System.out.println(farr[i]);
        }
    }
    public static String reverseString(String str){  
        char ch[]=str.toCharArray();  
        String rev="";  
        for(int i=ch.length-1;i>=0;i--){  
            rev+=ch[i];  
        }  
        return rev;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here, and I think in some places you're mixing up between strings and arrays.

Let's try to break this problem down into smaller problems.

First, we need to reverse a single word. Your first inner loop (the one that uses `j`) does that, so let's extract it into its own method:

```
public static String reverseWord(String word) {
    String reverseWord = "";
    for (int j = word.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        reverseWord = reverseWord + word.charAt(j);
    }
    return reverseWord;
}
```

Although, you should note that concatenating strings like that in a loop isn't great for performance, and using a `StringBuilder` would probably be faster (although with such a small application, it probably won't be noticeable):

```
public static String reverseWord(String word) {
    StringBuilder reverseWord = new StringBuilder(word.length());
    for (int j = word.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        reverseWord = reverseWord.append(word.charAt(j));
    }
    return reverseWord.toString();
}
```

Once you have that, you can split the input string (like you did), revere each word, and join them back together:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string to see it in reverse: ");
String userEntry = sc.nextLine();
String[] splitInput = userEntry.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < splitInput.length; i++) {
    splitInput[i] = reverseWord(splitInput[i]);
}
System.out.println("Your sttring with words spelled backwards is " + 
                   String.join(" ", splitInput));
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to split your original sentence into separate words and use `StringBuilder.reverse()` to get words in reverse:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String str = getSentenceFromConsole();
    System.out.println("Your string with words spelled backwards is '" + reversLettersInWords(str) + '\'');
}

private static String getSentenceFromConsole() {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Enter a string to see it in reverse: ");
        return scan.nextLine();
    }
}

private static String reversLettersInWords(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+"))
                 .map(word -> new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString())
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i try with your code

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string to see it in reverse: ");
    String userEntry = sc.nextLine();
    String[] splitInput = userEntry.split(" "); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < splitInput.length; i++) {
        String word = splitInput[i];
        for (int j = word.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            sb.append(word.charAt(j));
        }
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("Your sttring with words spelled backwards is " + sb.toString());
```

here i remove all access line of code....

Comment: Forget about string concatenation in the loop!

Comment: are you thinking `reverseWord = reverseWord + word.charAt(j);` this line in wrong...?

Comment: Yes + `reverseWord = reverseWord + " "`

Comment: but you know `reverseWord = reverseWord + word.charAt(j);` and `reverseWord += word.charAt(j);` both give same result....

Answer (score -1):

```
String input = "i love you";
StringBuilder input1 = new StringBuilder();
input1.append(input);
input1 = input1.reverse();
System.out.println(input1);
```

You can use this implementation to try to reverse the string elements in the array.

Comment: This will reverse the whole string, not the single words inside the string.